What preserves the tracelessness of irreducible Lie algebra representation of $SU(2)$ in QM?
In QM, we consider unitary, irreducible representations of the matrix group $SU(2)$ from $j=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots$ etc. The matrices $g\in SU(2)$ have determinant unity. However, the definition of group representation, a mapping from $SU(2)$ to $GL(V)$, does not enforce that the determinant has to be preserved. Therefore, except $j=1/2$ representation, I would not expect that the matrix generators corresponding to $j=1,3/2,2,5/2,\ldots$ representations to be traceless. Yet they turn out traceless, and the corresponding group representation matrices also have determinant equal to one. Why does this happen? What's being tacitly assumed in this construction which makes the irreps also unimodular?

Consider $J^{(j)}_z$ in the diagonal representation. Its diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of $J_z$. These eigenvalues are all of the numbers $-j, -j+1, \ldots, j-1,j$, where $j$ is integer or semi-integer. It is evident that the sum is zero. Since the trace is independent from the choice of the orthonormal basis, all that means that
$$tr(J^{(j)}_z)=0$$
just by using the basis of eigenvectors of $J^{(j)}_z$.
This fact is valid for every analogous operator $\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n$ where $n$ is any unit vector. That is because, from the theory of angular momentum
$$U_R \vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n U_R^\dagger =  \vec{J^{(j)}} \cdot Rn$$
where $U_R$ is the unitary representation of $SU(2)$ obtained by taking the exponentials of $\vec{J^{(j)}}$. Therefore
$$tr(\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n) = tr ( U_R (\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot R^{-1}n )U_R^\dagger) =
tr ( U_R^\dagger U_R (\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot R^{-1}n )) = tr (\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot R^{-1}n ) = tr J^{(j)}_z =0$$
where $R$ is such that $R e_z=n$.
Finally, since all the elements of the $j$-irrep are exponentials $e^{i \theta \vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n}$, we have that
$$det (e^{i \theta \vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n})= e^{i \theta tr(\vec{J^{(j)}}\cdot n)}= e^0=1$$ and unimodularity shows up.

OP's setting has the following natural 2-step generalization:

The determinant of a finite-dimensional representation of a simple Lie group is 1, c.f. e.g. this Math.SE post.

If $$\forall g\in G: \det(g)=1,$$ then $\forall x\in\mathfrak{g}: e^{{\rm tr}(x)}=\det(e^x)=1$, which implies tracelessness: $$\forall x\in\mathfrak{g}: {\rm tr}(x)=0.$$


